# Conflicting timestamps in JavaScript Azure Function

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

A timestamp returned by a JavaScript Azure Function is in the default UTC timezone, not the timezone set in the application settings.

I would like to compare timestamps using JavaScript code in an timer-triggered Azure function. If the first 15 characters of the timestamps match, an action is performed.

- The code to return the timestamp is `var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();`.
- The Azure Function's application settings include `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` | `Mountain State Time`.
- When I type `time` in the Azure Function's console, the current time in Mountain State Time is returned as expected.

**index.js**

```
      module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
         var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
         ...

         var timeStampB = result[i].CreatedDate;
         var timeStampBCut = timeStampB.substring(0, 15);

         var timeStampCut = timeStamp.substring(0, 15);

         if (new String(timeStampBCut).valueOf() == new String(timeStampCut).valueOf()) {
         ...
```

**function.json**

```
    {
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "myTimer",
          "type": "timerTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "schedule": "0 */25 * * * *"
        }
      ]
    }
```

(`timeStampB` is in Mountain State Time.)

When I test the `timeStamp` returned by `var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();`, the result is, for example, `2018-12-21T23:35:18.894Z`, which is UTC time. However when I enter `time` in the Azure Function's console, the time returned is Mountain State Time.

I would like the timestamps to be in the same timezone so I can compare the first 15 characters of both timestamps accurately.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'd just call `.getTime()` on both and make sure that the absolute value of the difference is less than 60000. The numeric timestamp values are always offsets from a fixed point in UTC time, so you don't have to worry about the implicit time zone adjustments that happen when you get a readable version of a Date instance.

Comment: Azure functions uses a worker architecture, so it's likely that the functions host and trigger are set to: `Mountain State Time`, but this is not propagating to the nodejs worker. 

In addition to this the JS function hosting runs in Windows: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/152 right now, you can check this thread: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4230 that also explains the TZ env variable doesn't work windows when running NodeJS.

Recommendations seem to be running: `tzutil /s "Mountain State Time"` or using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-tz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone) to convert the MST timestamp to UTC so it matched the Azure Function's time zone.

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var tz = 'America/Denver'
var mstTimeStampUtc = moment.tz(mstTimeStamp, tz).utc().format();
```